# Data not storing in localStorage in Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, session, mongoose, local-storage

Hello internet people,

I am trying to make an Angular 5 application with Mongoose as the back-end. Now I want to store data (an authentication token) in localStorage so that users keep their auth token after closing the page. This token is used to access our Mongoose endpoints.

When we try to access the token after logging in (you get the token after you log in) it does retrieve it (we saw so in the console log) but when we try to set it as a header for future requests it gives us a 403 forbidden error.

This is the error:

[image: Error from the console log]

This is the code which we use to initialize the headers and the localStorage with token:

```
private token = localStorage.getItem('token');
private headers = new Headers({'token': this.token});
public headerDict = new Headers({
    'token': this.token
  });

  public requestOptions = {
    headers: new Headers(this.headerDict),
  };
```

This is the method we try to use with the given header:

```
getUser() {
    console.dir(this.headers);
    console.log('tokenAndereManier: ' + localStorage.token);

    return this.http.get(this.serverUrl + (localStorage.userid || '5a3fd41e3ef7ccda81e7dda4'), { headers: this.headerDict})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        return response.json() as User;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return this.handleError(error);
      });
  }
```

Edit: [After changing headerdict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqpBN.png)

Comment: What is `this.token` referring in your frontend code? You intialize the code to a local variable, but later try to access it from the surrounding object. I'd say you're losing the token somewhere. Can you confirm it's there in the network panel?

Comment: What data (auth token) is the mongoose backend receiving? A 403 error indicates that the provided auth token (which I suspect might be empty, invalid or wrong) is not valid in the context of permissions in your application. You can check this in the network tab and tell us what headers are being send to the backend.

Comment: @JulienAmbos the mongoose backend is not recieving the auth token, it says 'null' as you can see in the image. This is weird because when we console.log the token it DOES show it. So when we try to send a header with the token, the value disappears.

Comment: Is it because the token is obtained asynchronously and you are trying to do the process synchronously?

Comment: It seems like you should be using "localStorage.token" instead of "this.token" in "headerDict"

Comment: @JulienAmbos I have tried that. Take a look at the image in my edit. The value is now "token" instead of the real token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `localStorage.token` in your console.log, but in your state you are trying to use `this.token`. Since the `this`property is only a reference to somewhere else I would recommend to use the `localStorage` prefix.